# Passport jwt and res.render

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

It is my first experience with passport-jwt. I configured the strategy and all works fine. I send token to client and extract it from the header with fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() method. But I got one issue, I want to render one specific page in case if Authorization header is empty or it doesn't set. How can I do it, except set up failureRedirect: '/specific-page' property?

The code of strategy is pretty standard:

```
JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (payload, done) => {
User.findOne({fmn_id: payload.data.id})
.then( (obj) => {
    if(!obj) throw new Error('No user with such id');
    done(null, obj);
})
.catch( (err) => {
    res.render('specificPage'); //In case of error I want to render this page. Current code doesn't work.
    done(null, err);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can render a specific template using `res.render('path_to_template')`
Suppose you have a template in your views directory called `myfile.ejs` then you can render to this by `res.render('myfile')`

Or you can also redirect user to another route using `res.redirect('/route');`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use pug and I have specificPage template in my view directory. But the problem is that I got Unauthorized page all the time. It seems to me that res.render() doesn't work in this case for some reason. I want to figure out why.